# IoC in the "real world" - how to handle many classes?

Tags: .net, structuremap, ioc-container

I now have a good understanding of DI and IoC containers, but I'm unsure how to handle the real-world aspects of having dozens of classes in multiple "modules" (DLLs, whatever).  Nearly all of the examples I've seen of IoC make use of maybe a handful of classes and manually set up the container in the Main method (or Global.asax if a web app) which is crazy for large-scale apps as you would have hundreds of lines just using the `For<I>().Use<T>()` syntax to set everything up.

I've done a bit of research and this seems to be the purpose of the Registry (StructureMap) and Kernel (Ninject) classes (those are the two IoC containers I'm familiar with so they're mentioned here - I'm sure other IoC containers have similar things).

Now, my question is are you intended to create a different Registry (I've been playing with StructureMap so I'll stick with that nomenclature) that corresponds to each grouping in your app (e.g. Repositories, Entities, Services) in let's say an "Infrastructure" class library, and then wire up those classes in the main application entry point?  I suppose you could go further and have one registry for each aggregate (to use the DDD term) and then wire all of those up in even broader registry classes that encompass an entire section of an application (e.g. The CRM part of a larger LOB app might have several aggregates by itself, so you'd have one registry wiring up each aggregate, and then a larger registry that combines all the aggregate registries.. I hope that made sense!)

For a basic example:

```
// MyApp.Infrastructure
class ServiceRegistry : Registry 
{
    public ServiceRegistry()
    {
        For<IOrderService>().Use<OrderService>();
        // other services...
    }
}

class RepositoryRegistry: Registry
{
    public RepositoryRegistry()
    {
        For<IOrderRepository>().Use<OrderRepository>();
        // other repositories...
    }
}

// other registry files e.g. for Entities

// Global.asax or Program.cs or whatever entry point
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => {
    x.AddRegistry<ServiceRegistry>();
    x.AddRegistry<RepositoryRegistry>();
    // other registries
});
```

Is this the preferred way of handling real-world apps that may have dozens, if not hundreds, of classes logically organized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In StructureMap, a registry aggregator is already provided.
Have a look at StructureMap's documentation on [scanning assemblies](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section4).
You should create a Registry for each assembly (you can do multiple in a single assembly, but there isn't any obvious benefit).

You can then use the scan functionality to find all of the registries. You will also want to make use of registration conventions (in the `Scan()` clause) so that you do not have to explicitly register each implementation.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => {
  x.Scan(s => {
    // Add the current assembly
    s.TheCallingAssembly();

    // Add all assembly from a specified path
    s.AssembliesFromPath("Extensions");

    // Automatically look and execute registries
    s.LookForRegistries();

    // specify some conventions
    s.WithDefaultConventions();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For larger projects like this, you'll probably want to favor convention over configuration.  StructureMap, for example, has a default convention scanner or you could write a custom scanner.  Take a look here: http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/20/create-your-own-auto-registration-convention-with-structuremap/

So, let's say you generally use constructor injection and your IoC bootstrapper can see exactly one implementation for interfaces in a given assembly, you'd just set it to scan that assembly and it'll wire up the constructor dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When I use Spring, I have separate configuration files by layer (web, service, persistence, etc.).  Like all layering techniques, these keep configurations that should logically be grouped together in one place that makes the relationship clear.

All of computer science has this in common: deal with complexity by decomposing it into smaller, more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Even the name Registry can be confusing although it is coming from Fowlers book of Design Patterns of Enterprise applications. You might consider calling the entry point the composition root of your application (see Marc Seemans .NET Dependency Injection, book from manning). 
Anyway, you should have a composition root for each and every application, not share the composition roots among applications as they tie interfaces with them while some applications might not need all your interfaces.

Hope that made some sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the IoC's "autowiring" feature. e.g. if you have separated implementations for your interfaces into different assemblies and are only distributing one version, the IoC-Container will be able to find a suitable implementation automatically and you don't have to manually tell the container which implementation it should use when resolving the dependency.

It's called "Autowiring" (byType, byName, ...) in [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-autowire) and [StructureMaps](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/AutoWiring.htm).